# Sending url using ajax on codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have this Ajax script where I pass a link to the data variable `link`, but I

> get a 412 error.

```
$(function() {
  $(".check-multi").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url('adm/updateproperty'); ?>",
      async: true,
      data: {
        link: $(this).data('link')
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        alert('Success');
        if (msg != 'success') {
          alert('Fail');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I have tried

```
link: encodeURI($(this).data('link'))
```

And

```
link: encodeURIComponent($(this).data('link'))
```

as is suggested on other threads but I still get the `412 error` message.

Comment: always  accept  answer by ticking it as green if you find it helps you

Comment: @pradeep Thanks. None of the answers solved my issue... I ended up removing the `http://` part of the before sending it and adding it server side. Thats why I didn't checked any of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code in data options. Use this way

```
data: {"id": ID},
```

i.e. store the value in a variable and send that variable in data option. If we assume

```
ID=$(this).data('link');`
```

Then the code will be as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $(".check-multi").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url('adm/updateproperty'); ?>",
      async: true,
      data: {"id":ID},
      success: function(msg) {
        alert('Success');
        if (msg != 'success') {
          alert('Fail');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Please check it.

Comment: What's the difference? Changing name of variable?

Comment: There is no difference in changing the variable name. I want to tell you that you do your code in this way. first assign the value in a variable i.e. ID=$(this).data('link'); then send the value on that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

you have added newline character to `json` data that is why you got error

Do like this :

```
var link = $(this).data('link');
data: {"link" : link},

/*----OR do this -----*/

data: {"link" : $(this).data('link')},
```

instead of this :

```
data: {
        link: $(this).data('link')
      },
```

Whole code should be like this :

```
var link = $(this).data('link');
/*console.log(link)*/
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url('adm/updateproperty'); ?>",
      async: true,
      data: {"link" : link },
      success: function(msg) {
        alert('Success');
        if (msg != 'success') {
          alert('Fail');
        }
      }
    });
```

For More :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412